# How to solve " 'takeown' is not recognized as an internal or external command "

Tags: command, cygwin, uninstallation

I am trying to **uninstall cygwin** debugger from my system. In order to uninstall we have to take ownership of the application.
But when I enter **takeown** command it says **'takeown' is not recognized** as internal or external command. (I have tried it in administrator CMD still same problem)

This command takes ownership recursive of the folder, without asking anything:
**takeown /r /d y /f cygwin**

This command gives Full Access to Everyone recursively in the folder:
**icacls cygwin /t /grant Everyone:F**

And finally, the command which deletes it all and removes Cygwin:
**rmdir /s /q cygwin**

Comment: `takeown.exe` should be in the `System32` directory. What System are you using ?

Comment: Sir / Mam, I didn't understand " What System are you using ? " means . If you mean **operating system** I am **using Windows 10**. And as you told I checked in System32 directory, takeown.exe still exists there. Please reply @matzeri .

Comment: Well, now I cleared the Takeown issue by **Editing the value of Path** in Advanced System Setings -> Environment Variable -> System Variables by **C:\Windows\System32;**.  Thank you @matzeri